# Graph of Derivative function

Tags: tikz-pgf, graphs

How could i draw these graphs in latex. The formula of function is labeled as (5.7) in the given picture. Please see : [image: FIGURE]

MWE:

I am trying with the the following format to create the graph given above, but since I am totally unaware of plotting graph in `LaTeX`, so it failed. I have posted the whole format to avoid any misunderstanding.

```
\documentclass[a4,11pt,twosided,reqno]{amsart}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage[noadjust]{cite}
\usepackage{amscd,amssymb}
\usepackage[arrow,matrix]{xy}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{color}


\topmargin=0.1in \textwidth5.9in \textheight7.85in
\oddsidemargin=0.3in \evensidemargin=0.3in \theoremstyle{plain}
\newfont{\black}{msbm10 scaled 1200}

\def\la{\langle}
\def\ra{\rangle}
\def\Rn{\mbox{\black R}^{n}}
\def\R{\mbox{\black R}}
\def\Rm{\mbox{\black R}^{m}}
\def\t{\widetilde}
\def\h{\widehat}

\def\R{\mbox{\black R}}
\def\C{\mbox{\black C}}

\def\Rn{\mbox{\black R}^{n}}
\def\Cn{\mbox{\black C}^{n}}
\def\Fn{\mbox{\black F}^{n}}
\def\Mn{\mbox{\black M}_{n}}

\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}
\newtheorem{lemma}{Lemma}
\newtheorem{proposition}{Proposition}
\newtheorem{applications}[subsection]{Applications}
\newtheorem{cor}{Corollary}
\theoremstyle{definition}
\newtheorem{definition}{Definition}
\newtheorem{rk}{Remark}
\newtheorem{example}{Example}
\newtheorem{question}[subsection]{Question}
\DeclareMathOperator{\id}{id} \DeclareMathOperator{\sgn}{sgn}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[yscale=1.5]
\draw [help lines, <->] (0,0) -- (6.5,0);
\draw [help lines, ->] (0,-1.1) -- (0,1.1);
\draw [green,domain=0:2*pi] plot (\x, {(sin(\x r)* ln(\x+1))/2});
\draw [red,domain=0:pi] plot (\x, {sin(\x r)});
\draw [blue, domain=pi:2*pi] plot (\x, {cos(\x r)*exp(\x/exp(2*pi))});
\end{tikzpicture}


\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! This sounds like a do-it-for-me question. Please have a look at the manual of the `pgfplots` package. That will be a starter.

Comment: Or try the `\datavisualization` functionality as explained in chapter 74ff in the pgf manual, http://ctan.org/pkg/pgf  There are many ways to Rome. You can also calculate points of the formula in an external application of your choice (matlab, maple, mathematica…) and plot the resulting points.

Comment: I added your answer to your question.

Answer (score 2):

Here's some code that gets you part of the way there.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fullpage}
\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{datavisualization}
\usetikzlibrary{datavisualization.formats.functions}

% ln Gamma(z) is approximately
%   [ln(2pi) - ln z]/2 + z[ln( z + 1/(12z - 1/(10z)) ) - 1]
% ln(2pi) = 0.79818
\newcommand*\LnGamma[1]{%
    (0.79818-ln(#1))/2 + (#1)*(ln((#1) + 1/(12*(#1) - 1/(10*(#1)))) - 1)
}

% Generalized fractional derivative of the power function.
% \gfdpf{nu}{alpha}
\newcommand*\gfdpf[2]{%
    \begin{tikzpicture}[baseline]
        \pgfmathsetmacro\coeffA{exp(\LnGamma{1+#1/0.4}-\LnGamma{1+#1/0.4-#2}+(#2-1)*ln(0.4))}%
        \pgfmathsetmacro\coeffB{exp(\LnGamma{1+#1/1.0}-\LnGamma{1+#1/1.0-#2}+(#2-1)*ln(1.0))}%
        \pgfmathsetmacro\coeffC{exp(\LnGamma{1+#1/1.4}-\LnGamma{1+#1/1.4-#2}+(#2-1)*ln(1.4))}%
        \datavisualization[scientific axes=clean,%
            visualize as smooth line/.list={r1,r2,r3},%
            style sheet=vary dashing,%
            visualizer color=red,%
            legend={south outside, matrix node style=draw},%
            r1={label in legend={text=\ensuremath{\rho=0.4}}},%
            r2={label in legend={text=\ensuremath{\rho=1.0}}},%
            r3={label in legend={text=\ensuremath{\rho=1.4}}},%
            data/format=function]%
        data[set=r1]{%
            var x : interval [0:3];%
            func y = \coeffA*\value x^(#1-#2*0.4);%
        }%
        data[set=r2]{%
            var x : interval [0:3];%
            func y = \coeffB*\value x^(#1-#2*1.0);%
        }%
        data[set=r3]{%
            var x : interval [0:3];%
            func y = \coeffC*\value x^(#1-#2*1.4);%
        };%
        \end{tikzpicture}%
}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
\centering
\subfloat[$\nu=1.0$]{\gfdpf{1.0}{1}}\quad
\subfloat[$\nu=2.0$]{\gfdpf{2.0}{1}}

\subfloat[$\nu=0.5$]{\gfdpf{0.5}{1}}\quad
\subfloat[$\nu=1.5$]{\gfdpf{1.5}{1}}
\caption{Generalized fractional derivative of the power function $f(x)=x^\nu$
for $\rho=0.4,1.0,1.4$ and $\nu=0.5,1.0,1.5,2.0$.}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Obviously, this code has some issues.

1. The function being computed is either not correct or some part of the computation went outside the range `pgfmath` could handle. I didn't investigate which. My general strategy was to approximate the log gamma function instead of gamma to prevent values from being too large. That is, I tried to prevent values from going outside the valid range. So more likely is I simply screwed up my arithmetic.
2. The legend entries aren't straight lines. (That's probably easy to fix. I didn't try.)
3. The dash pattern set by `vary dashing` doesn't match the dash pattern in the picture. It's possible to define one's own style sheets so this could be changed by duplicating and modifying the `vary dashing` style sheet.

Hopefully, you can take this as a starting point.

Comment: The legends line are very nice indeed. How did you manage to make them? I like them more than the straight lines!!!!

Comment: @Rmano, I didn't do anything special for that. `label in legend` seems to do it by default.

Comment: Ah, ok. Seems the default for `datavisualization`, I missed the fact that this answer was *not* using `pgfplots`. Now I have to find how to do it with `pgfplots`... thanks!